# How do I create a block that has links to site registration and forgot password programmatically?

Tags: blocks

Can anyone help me writing code for a block containing the "Register" and "Forgot your password?" links that are shown to the anonymous users?

Comment: Which users should see the "Forgot your password?" link?

Comment: More importantly, why do you need such block when there is already the "User login" block which contains a "Create new account" and a "Request new password" links?

Comment: anonymous users... I just need know how to write these independantly ... I'm not using the user login default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to learn, I suggest, look at the relevant part of drupal core:
[`user_block_info()`](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/b9127101ffeca819e74a03fa9f5a48d026c562e5:/modules/user/user.module#l1333) - this is the block info definition.

[`user_block_view()`](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/b9127101ffeca819e74a03fa9f5a48d026c562e5:/modules/user/user.module#l1399) - This builds the renderable array of block.

You see here `$block['content'] = drupal_get_form('user_login_block');` This makes the complete user login form. If you want to show only the two link, just change this to something like this:

```
$block['content'] = array(
  '#markup' => 'the pure html of your links',
);
```

To check, how to generate the core these links, see the [`user_login_block()`](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/b9127101ffeca819e74a03fa9f5a48d026c562e5:/modules/user/user.module#l1318) in core. The line 1323 is the html markup in you block's content, what do you need

Comment: ok here is my code: ... what did I do wrong I keep getting errors...

Comment: if (variable_get('user_register', USER_REGISTER_VISITORS_ADMINISTRATIVE_APPROVAL)) {
print " | ";
print print l(t('Register'),'user/register', array(
    'query' => array(
      'destination' =>  $destination
     )
  )
);
}

Comment: To paste your code use this: http://paste2.org/
But it's sure, the the print doesn't need.
And just hope, you use D7.

Answer (score 0):

I take you are creating a module to show a block containing those two links. I would use the following code, in that case.

```
function mymodule_block_info() {
  $blocks['login']['info'] = t('User login');
  $blocks['login']['cache'] = DRUPAL_NO_CACHE;

  return $blocks;
}

function mymodule_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'login':
      if (!user_is_logged_in()) {
        $links = array();
        $links['register'] = array(
          'title' => t('Register'), 
          'href' => url('the link to your registration page'),
        );
        $links['forgot-password'] = array(
          'title' => t('Forgot your password?'), 
          'href' => url('the link to your page to get a new password'),
        );

        $block['subject'] = t('User login');
        $block['content'] = array(
          '#theme' => 'links',
          '#links' => $links,
        );
      }

      return $block;
  }
}
```

If you need the code that you use in admin/structure/block/add to create a new block, then you should use the following code in "Block body."

```
<?php
  $links = array();
  $links['register'] = array(
    'title' => t('Register'), 
    'href' => url('the link to your registration page'),
  );
  $links['forgot-password'] = array(
    'title' => t('Forgot your password?'), 
    'href' => url('the link to your page to get a new password'),
  );

  print theme('links', array('links' => $links));
```

In "Show block on specific pages," select "Pages on which this PHP code returns `TRUE` (experts only)," and enter `<?php return !user_is_logged_in(); ?>` in the text area shown behind.

The text format must be "PHP code," which means the PHP filter module must be enabled.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

You need also to assign a region to the block, or it will never appear.

Comment: not as a module  ... ...(where and how do I use this)...thanx... I need the UI 'new-block' code snippet... if its any different